# Hello ! I'm trying to print image (esc_pos_utils_plus: ^2.0.2 ), and catch RangeError

Tags: flutter, printing

`final ByteData data = await rootBundle.load("assets/images/logo.png"); final Uint8List lis = data.buffer.asUint8List(); final im.Image? img = im.decodeImage(lis); bytes += generator.imageRaster(img!);`

`E/flutter (29670): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in inclusive range 0..152976: 152977 E/flutter (29670): #0      List.[] (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:177:60) E/flutter (29670): #1      Ticket._packBitsIntoBytes (package:esc_pos_utils/src/ticket.dart:566:16) E/flutter (29670): #2      Ticket._toRasterFormat (package:esc_pos_utils/src/ticket.dart:675:12) E/flutter (29670): #3      Ticket.imageRaster (package:esc_pos_utils/src/ticket.dart:694:38) E/flutter (29670): #4      _PrinterEntryState.testTicket (package:project/printerEntry.dart:556:15) E/flutter (29670): <asynchronous suspension> E/flutter (29670): #5      _PrinterEntryState.testPrint (package:project/printerEntry.dart:503:24) E/flutter (29670): <asynchronous suspension> E/flutter (29670):`

print logo on receipt check

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.